# Thread Blocks in server mode

Tags: java

This method notifes an event loop to start processing a message. However, if the event loop is already processing a message then, this method blocks until it receives a notification of completed event processing (which is triggered at the end of the event loop).

```
public void processEvent(EventMessage request) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("processEvent");

    if (processingEvent) {
        synchronized (eventCompleted) {
            System.out.println("processEvent: Wait for Event to completed");
            eventCompleted.wait();
            System.out.println("processEvent: Event completed");
        }
    }

    myRequest = request;
    processingEvent = true;
    synchronized (eventReady) {
        eventReady.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

This works in client mode. If I switch to server mode and the time spent in the event loop processing the message is too quick, then the method above blocks forever waiting for the event to completed. For some reason the event complete notification is sent after the processingEvent check and before the eventCompleted.wait(). It makes no difference if I remove the output statements. I can not repeat the same problem in client mode.

Why does this only happen in server mode and what can I do to prevent this happening?

Here is the eventReady wait and eventCompleted notification:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (eventReady) {
                    eventReady.wait();
                }
                nx.processEvent(myRequest, myResultSet);
                if (processingEvent > 0) {
                    notifyInterface.notifyEventComplete(myRequest);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                notifyInterface.notifyException(e, myRequest);
            } finally {
                processingEvent--;
                synchronized (eventCompleted) {
                    eventCompleted.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } // End of while loop
    } catch (InterruptedException Ignore) {
    } finally {
        me = null;
    }
```

Here is revised code which seems to work without the deadlock problem - which BTW happened in client mode randomely after about 300 events.

```
private BlockingQueue<EventMessage> queue = new SynchronousQueue<EventMessage>();

public void processEvent(EventMessage request) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("processEvent");

    queue.put(request);
}


public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            EventMessage request = null;
            try {
                request = queue.take();
                processingEvent = true;
                nx.processEvent(request, myResultSet);
                notifyInterface.notifyEventComplete(request);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                notifyInterface.notifyException(e, request);
            } finally {
                if (processingEvent) {
                    synchronized (eventCompleted) {
                        processingEvent = false;
                        eventCompleted.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        } // End of while loop
    } catch (InterruptedException Ignore) {
    } finally {
        me = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of race conditions in your code.  Even declaring `processingEvent` `volatile` or using an `AtomicBoolean` won't help.  I would recommend using a [`SynchronousQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) which will block the event until the processer is ready for it.  Something like:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Request> queue = new SynchronousQueue<Request>();
...

// this will block until the processor dequeues it
queue.put(request);
```

Then the event processor does:

```
while (!done) {
   // this will block until an event is put-ed to the queue
   Request request = queue.take();
   process the event ...
}
```

Only one request will be processed at once and all of the synchronization, etc. will be handled by the `SynchronousQueue`.

Comment: I implemented your method before I saw your comment. It works great now!

Comment: I believe that you mean to have a LinkedBlockingQueue with a limit of 1, not 0.  Per the API docs, a limit of 0 will throw an IllegalArgumentException in the constructor.

Comment: No.  1 will make it queue 1 event.  1 working and 1 queued.  0 means that the provider will block until it is dequeued by the event processor.  No events are queued.  0 is a typical pattern.

Comment: What version of the JDK?  Just tested in 1.6 and got an exception, 1.7 javadocs indicate the same behaviour (but the docs could be wrong I suppose).

Comment: Working with JDK 1.5 but I need to implement in a way to work with JDK 1.6 and 1.7 too. But I didn't define a limit.

Comment: Oops.  You are correct.  SynchronousQueue is what is needed.  LinkedBlockingQueue(1) throws.  Sorry.

Comment: I tried with SynchronousQueue but with add method I get an illegal state on the second event. If I use the put method then it will block the calling thread until the event is taken off the queue. I want a way limit time the calling thread is blocked. What I need is a put with a time limit.

Comment: You need one more fix, SynchronousQueue does not take a limit (it is always a "1" element queue (or 0 element, depending on which method you use to put elements into it)).

Comment: @mtse use offer(object, timeLimit, timeUnit)

Comment: Thanks. Using SynchronousQueue  and method offer is better - much simplier than what I was trying to do.

Comment: You sure you want to drop events on the floor if they aren't processed in time?  Maybe you should go back to the blocking queue and put a limit on it and use offer there?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. The calling thread cannot block for too long because it prevents other potential events from happening. If an event cannot be processed within a certain time then I'll throw an exception and pass back to calling process a busy message.

Answer (score 1):

If you call notifyAll and no thread is wait()ing, the notify is lost.

The correct approach is to always change a state, inside the synchronized block, when calling notify() and always check that state, inside the synchronized block, before calling wait().

Also your use of processingEvent doesn't appear to be thread safe.

Can you provide the code which waits on `eventReady` and notifies `eventCompleted`?

Your program can happen to work if your speed up or slow down your application just right e.g. if you use `-client`, but if you use a different machine, JVM or JVM options it can fail.

Comment: You mention checking a state before calling wait(), but the problem is that there will always be a gap between checking the state and calling wait, so you need some type of synchronization to prevent a race condition (regardless of how / when the state is updated).

Comment: @increment1 Thank you. Have added a clarification.

Comment: I think that the added synchronization blocks in your description may cause a deadlock issue since if you mean to synchronize on the same lock then if the waiting thread is holding that lock, then the releasing thread will never be able to acquire the lock and trigger the notify.

Comment: @increment1 wait() releases the lock and acquires it again before waking up. There is not chance of a deadlock if you have only one lock (but you can get a deadlock with two locks)

Comment: I think we may be talking about different locks here.  In your updated description you refer to two synchronized blocks (unless you mean that there is only one synchronized block that all the code exists in), I am assuming that these blocks lock on the same object, in which case if you wait() in one block then the other block (block with the notify code) cannot be entered since the synchronized statement will be trying to acquire the lock on the already held synchronization object.

Comment: @increment1 Like I said wait() releases the lock so there is no chance of a deadlock with a single lock.

Comment: This is something genuinely new to me, so can you tell me you release the lock held by an enclosing synchronization block with a wait statement (if it is possible I genuinely want to know)?  E.g. synchronized(myLock) { myObject.wait(); }  How is myLock released by wait()?

Comment: From the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29 `The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. `

Comment: Gotcha, I was not considering that you were obviously (and necessarily) synchronizing on the same object that you were waiting (I was assuming a lock on a different object).

Answer (score 0):

If `processingEvent` isn't declared `volatile` or accessed from within a `synchronized` block then updates made by one thread may not become visible to other threads immediately. It's not clear from your code whether this is the case, though.

The "server" VM is optimised for speed (at the expense of startup time and memory usage) which could be the reason why you didn't encounter this problem when using the "client" VM.

Answer (score 0):

There is a race condition in your code that may be exasperated by using the server VM, and if processingEvent is not volatile then perhaps certain optimizations made by the server VM or its environment are further influencing the problem.

The problem with your code (assuming this method is accessed by multiple threads concurrently) is that between your check of processingEvent and eventCompleted.wait(), another thread can already notify and (I assume) set processingEvent to false.

The simplest solution to your blocking problem is to not try to manage it yourself, and just let the JVM do it by using a shared lock (if you only want to process one event at a time).  So you could just synchronize the entire method, for instance, and not worry about it.

A second simple solution is to use a SynchronousQueue (this is the type of situation it is designed for) for your event passing; or if you have more executing threads and want more than 1 element in the queue at a time then you can use an ArrayBlockingQueue instead.  Eg:

```
private SynchronousQueue<EventMessage> queue = new SynchronousQueue<EventMessage>();  

public void addEvent(EventMessage request) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Adding event");

    queue.put(request);
}

public void processNextEvent()
{
  EventMessage request = queue.take();
  processMyEvent(request);
}

// Your queue executing thread
public void run()
{
  while(!terminated)
  {
    processNextEvent();
  }
}
```

Comment: I used LinkedBlockingQueue because I needed FIFO and also the ability to control how long to block the calling thread to processEvent for.

Comment: @mtse SynchronousQueue has no size, and is essentially one element only (it has the same functionality as a LinkedBlockingQueue of size 1, just better performance I would assume).  All queues have FIFO capability, and all of the blocking queues have the ability to block for a limited time via offer and poll.  If you like Gray's answer then you should upvote it (up arrow) and accept it (check mark).

Comment: I would up vote but I don't have high enough reputation - this is my first question on Stackoverflow!